# Parse Method For Different Classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I want to inheritance different classes from one interface that it contains Parse method like this:

```
interface IDataContract
{
    IDataContract Parse(string s);
}

class Date:IDataContract
{
    public Date Parse(string s)
    {
         return new Date();
    }
}

class Time:IDataContract
{
    public Time Parse(string s)
    {
         return new Time();
    }
}
```

But occurs a compile-time error. How can I do this?

Comment: Do Time and Date classes implement IDataContract?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, you cannot change the method signature in this way. You could use generics for a similar effect, however:

```
interface IDataContract<T>
{
    T Parse(string s);
}

class Date : IDataContract<Date>
{
    public Date Parse(string s)
    {
         return new Date();
    }
}

class Time : IDataContract<Time>
{
    public Time Parse(string s)
    {
         return new Time();
    }
}
```

In general you won't be able to get around the fact that to do anything useful with it, the caller has to know what the string represents. Or else `IDataContract` has to contain other useful methods, or extend an interface which does.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the signature of method in derived class. Return type should be `IDataContract`.

```
class Date : IDataContract
{
    public IDataContract Parse(string s)
    {
         return new Date();
    }
}

class Time : IDataContract
{
    public IDataContract Parse(string s)
    {
         return new Time();
    }
}
```